# Why isn't the text on my "video loading" button changing?

Tags: java, button

I have a button that plays a rewarded ad, but it takes a few seconds for the ad to load.  I want the button text to cycle between "Video loading." "Video loading.." and "Video loading..."

I've used the following runnable for this:

```
public Runnable CountDown = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        btnVideoStarts.setText("Video loading.");
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        btnVideoStarts.setText("Video loading..");
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        btnVideoStarts.setText("Video loading...");
        if (rewardedInterstitialAd != null) {
            btnVideoStarts.setText("Start video");
            handler.removeCallbacks(CountDown);
        }
    }
};
```

The button shows "Video loading..." the whole time until it changes to "Start video".

Does anyone know why it's only showing those two labels?

I used to have a countdown timer that worked.  Here's the code for it:

```
public Runnable CountDown = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        btnVideoStarts.setText("Video ready in " + String.valueOf(buttonCount)+"s");
        buttonCount --;
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        if (buttonCount ==0) {
            btnVideoStarts.setText("Start Video");
            handler.removeCallbacks(CountDown);
        }
    }
};
```

The only problem was that the load times varied, so I figured I'd be better off just saying "Video loading..." rather than have the countdown expire before the video was ready.

I don't understand why the old code worked, but the new code doesn't.  Can someone show me where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a 100 percent sure, but as fas as I understand `handler.postDelayed()` from
this explanation

> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run
> after the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run
> on the thread to which this handler is attached. The time-base is
> SystemClock.uptimeMillis(). Time spent in deep sleep will add an
> additional delay to execution.

you will just add it to a queue, and execute it after 1000ms, so it won't delay the current execution, but will start the run() method again, after 1000ms.
To break down your code:

```
public Runnable CountDown = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        btnVideoStarts.setText("Video loading."); // sets the text to "Video loading."
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // adds itself to a queue, but won't stop the execution of this run through
        btnVideoStarts.setText("Video loading.."); // sets the text to "Video loading.."
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        btnVideoStarts.setText("Video loading..."); // Finally sets the text to what you will always see, because the time window, between the text changes is to small
        if (rewardedInterstitialAd != null) {
            btnVideoStarts.setText("Start video");
            handler.removeCallbacks(CountDown);
        }
    }
};
```

So essentially, you're generating a loop, with both of you're methods, as both will call themselves (delayed), your second method works, because you don't set the text twice in the method.
If you want to wait inside a Runnable, use `Thread.sleep(ms)` and a loop, that stops, when the video is loaded